# Is it any Firefox extensions that will let you run a tab with chromes engine?(Like IETab)

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, firefox-extensions, chromium, ietab

There is an extension for Firefox and Google chrome that let's you run tabs on Internet Explorer's render engine, so it will be displayed just like if you opened it in IE.

### Is there any similar extension for Firefox that will let you have chrome tabs?

This can be very helpful on some sites that has chrome only features, often video players or sound tools, and the likes.

Comment: not what you asked, but [Open In Chrome](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/open-in-chrome/) will move a tab in firefox to chrome. But not run chrome in a firefox tab, instead it closes the tab, and add a tab to a running chrome instance, or start chrome if it was not running.

Comment: @Wimmel I know about the "open in chrome" extensions, and they make a nice backup solution. However I think it would be nice to have chrome in a tab.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome Frame claims to be open-source, so maybe one could be made. I don't know the details.

https://developers.google.com/chrome/chrome-frame/

There were lots of rumours in 2009 (Google it) but nothing's obviously happened since, and development has/will soon be stopped.

Comment: (Sorry for late reply) I couldn't find the source code?

Comment: Neither could I.